# Congruence in AKS algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primality-test

In the AKS algorithm, we consider the congruence

$$(X+a)^n \equiv X^n + a \pmod{X^r-1}$$

in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[X]$. The motivation for this is that when taking $r$ in the order of $\log n$, we will always be dealing with polynomials in the order of $\log n$.

It is argued that we take $X^r-1$ because of its simplicity. Why wouldn't we consider the congruence modulo $X^r$, which perhaps could be seen as an even simpler polynomial. Is there an intuitive answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the original [paper](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf), in a series of statements to prove the algorithm can't label a composite number a 'prime', they use a few properties of cyclotomic polynomials after Lemma 4.6. In particular, they define a group $\mathcal{G}$ which would definitely not be a group if we take $h(X)$ a factor of $X^r$ instead of $X^r - 1$: as $h$ has repeated factors (unless $\deg h = 1$, but that case is trivial), the quotient ring $F_p[X]/(h(X))$ they allude to would contain nontrivial nilpotents.

Comment: I can see that when if we take $h$ as an irreducible factor of $X^r$, then it must be $X$. Then $F_p[X]/(h(X)) = F_p$ and $\mathcal{G}$ will not be a group anymore since it contains $0$. However, this feels like looking too much ahead in the proof to find out why it doesn't work. Is there a more intuitive way to see why $X^r-1$ would be more suitable?

Comment: In OP, you write "It is argued that..." Could you please provide a source, if possible? The main proof starts with L4.3, where they give bounds for the smallest $r$ such that $o_r(n)$ is large enough — and this $o_r(p)$ is the degree of $h$. The complexity bound — the main achievement of AKS — directly depends on L4.3. After L4.6 they even say "two groups ... will play a *crucial* role in the proof". For a random polynomial, it *might* take longer than $\sqrt{r} \log n$ tries to find out a composite; but, I'm afraid, to see *why* it is enough for $X^r-1$, you'll have to go into detail.

Comment: In Granville's paper ([link](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/S0273-0979-04-01037-7.pdf)) he says on page 13 that "The simplest polynomial of degree $r$ is perhaps $X^r− 1$." That triggered the question I posted.